# Change Dimension of nested layout in MotionLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I do have a nested layout in a MotionLayout by using an `<include>`.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
...>
   <include android:id="@+id/incl"
        layout="@layout/layout2"/>
    ...
</<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Layout2 file is as follows:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="16sp"

    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:text="B"
        android:textSize="16sp"

    />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv3"
        android:text="C"
        android:textSize="16sp"

    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want to do is to change the textSize to 20 sp when Animation of the MotionLayout Ends.

Motionlayout animation is basic just some grow Animation by changing dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

A `MotionLayout` can only animate the properties of its direct children. You can bring your `Views` out of the inner `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: But the Include layout is used multiple times. Is there any whay it can be achieved using Kotlin or java

Comment: The only option is to animate the nested layout on its own. To do that, you can either make `MotionLayout` the parent of your nested layout or you can animate nested views programmatically in Java or Kotlin.